# cannot cast to jsonb if non-negative numeric vlaue have plus sign

Tags: postgresql

the following command working

```
select '[0,1, -2,  -0.3444, 5.6]'::jsonb;
```

However the following 3 not working.

```
select '[0,1, -2,  (+0.3444), 5.6]'::jsonb;
select '[0,1, -2,  +0.3444, 5.6]'::jsonb;
select '[0,1, -2,  +0, 5.6]'::jsonb;
```

The following working.

```
select +0.1;
select (+0.1)::text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first working example is a string containing a valid JSON document being cast as JSONB; the other ones contain valid PostgreSQL arithmetic expressions.

The non-working examples again have strings being cast into JSONB, but the strings contain *invalid* JSON expressions, and thus cannot be parsed as JSON. If you take a look at [JSON grammar](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), `number` is `integer fraction exponent`, and `integer` can have digits that optionally start with `-`. The sign `+` is not allowed in JSON. The parentheses are not allowed, either. You can verify this e.g. using [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/).